# Reading text file and skipping blank lines in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-files

I have the below code which appends the content of a text file to my `RichTextBox1`.

```
Dim FileName = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "CLIENT HISTORY\" & TextBox1.Text))

For Each ClientDetailsCHT As FileInfo In FileName.GetFiles("*.CHT", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(ClientDetailsCHT.FullName))
Next
' Send to printing sub
```

This works fine.

The problem I am having is that this text file sometimes contains blank lines and I would like to skip those blank lines so that the code only appends text to the `RichTextBox`.

How can I re-write my code to achieve this? I am using Visual Basic 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the lines and skip the ones that are blank. The following code skips lines that are empty or only contain white space. If you only want to skip empty lines, change IsNullOrWhiteSpace to IsNullOrEmpty.

```
Dim FileName = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "CLIENT HISTORY\" & TextBox1.Text))

For Each ClientDetailsCHT As FileInfo In FileName.GetFiles("*.CHT", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(ClientDetailsCHT.FullName)
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then RichTextBox1.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)
    Next
Next
' Send to printing sub
```